# How to live stream RTMP video across PHP, and into a video element like YouTube?

Tags: php, html, video, youtube, rtmp

From what I can see on YouTube, they use an `<embed>` element to include live streamed video onto their page, which they retrieve from a `blob:` URL.

I currently have an `rtmp://` URL set up, and I want to be able to play its contents in my browser like how YouTube did, with no flash.

How is this possible? A solution involving PHP is prefered.

Comment: You're going to have to look at the RTMP specifications PDF. Apart from the whole server/client handshake stuff, when you get to the RTMP packets you'll have to extract the h.264 data out of those packets (sometimes multiple packets to hold one video frame). You'll have to know how to recognise the start & end of an h.264 NAL unit. So assuming, for example, that spread over 3 packets are the start, middle & end bytes of a h.264 frame, you read past each packet's header bytes & extract the h.264 then join all 3 parts (bytes) to make one NAL and therefore a blob representing a video frame...

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any solution for playing RTMP without Flash, but if you can encode the video in HLS or MPEG-DASH as well, you would be able to use JavaScript libraries to play it.